# How to configure securely pg_hba.conf postgresql.conf to connect to postgresql database server

Tags: linux, postgresql, security, digital-ocean

I want to configure my DigitalOcean Postgresql database, for **to use pg_dumb** from home, and I can't get it working correctly:

It works with pg_hba-conf:

```
host all all all md5
```

and in postgresaql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

But I don't want to use "all" and "*" bacause, I guess, it is not secure.

I think, after reading Postgresql docs ([pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), and [authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SECURITY), and more...) I should use my IP in this two files:

- pg_hba.conf: `host all all xxx.xxx.xx.xx/32 md5`
- postgresql.conf: `listen_addresses = 'localhost,xxx.xxx.xx.xx'`

But I can't understand this issues:

1. If I put `listen_addresses='*'` in postgresql.conf, it doesn't matter what IP I put in pg_hba.conf ! **it works with any ip** ¿?¿? for example `host  all  all  113.147.107.52/0 md5`
2. And If I put `listen_addresses='localhost,[my_IP]'` in postgresql.conf, it doesn't work: `connection to database "c..ion" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused`.

   In `[my_IP]`, I put what I get from ipecho.net, is that Ip correct?

This is pg_hba.conf, the last entry is what I wolud like to give access only to me

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local    all            postgres                               md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             rails                                   peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# For copy from home with pg_dumb, this IP is random: all IPs allow me to execute pg_dum if in listen_address='*'
host    all              all            my_ip_from_ipecho.net/32           md5
```

I think I need more knowledge of IPs, besides that I am absolutely lost

( PD: At the end, I supose I will execute pg_dump within the  server, and then, from my home PC, I will copy these backup files with `scp`. But I would like to understand whats happening and how it works )

Thanks a lot

Comment: listen_addresses is the list of server addresses that the server listens on. It has nothing to do with the clients connecting to it.

Comment: but If I put ´listen_addresses='*'´ I can execute pg_dumb from my PC, If not, pg_dumb returns error connection. Is that normal?

Comment: Shouldn't the IP address in you pg_hba.conf file be specified as "113.147.107.52/32" instead of "113.147.107.52/0"?

Comment: I tried xxx.xxx.xx.xx/32 too in pg_hba.conf, and no mather what I put in xxx.xxx.... I can connect allways. I will edit de question with the content of this file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the ip adresses in postgresql.conf, you will have to confiure ALL the ips your clients will be comming from (including in this case your PC ip or VPN if you are using).

That's is why it works when you use '*', because it will listen for clients comming from all ips (including yours).

pg_hba.conf will work as a firewall, so you will need to configure your entrance there too.

In your case , I think is better to use listen_addresses='*' ,and configure the ip adrresses in pg_hba, as the parameter listen_addresses requires a restart when you want to change it.

```
pg_hba.conf: host all all xxx.xxx.xx.xx/0 md5
postgresql.conf: listen_addresses = '*'
```

Just tell me if you need further help to configure your pg_hba.

Good luck!

Note: further information on the listen_adresses parameter
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: I understood that if listen_addresses defaults is "localhost", the postgresql server only listen for my web application installed on the same server ('localhost'). All clients that browse to web, connect to postgresql through my server web application (localhost). But after reading docs (again): `The default value is localhost, which allows only local TCP/IP "loopback" connections to be made`...I understand "localhost" acts as a exception

Comment: I've edited the question, adding the pg_hba.conf file, and I don't know how to configure this "Firewall", because, as I said, I can access always, although I put another IP in the last entry from pg_hba.conf (if I put listen_addresses='*'

Comment: You can try by setting a wrong password to get an error,  and look at your postgresql log to see what pg_hba entry is using. The error will you wich line in pg_hba is matching.